# Is it good practice to mix yield and return statements in python?

Tags: python

I'd quite like to have the following behaviour:

```
def foo(bar=None):
    if bar:
        return other_function(other_thing[bar])
    else:
        for i in other_thing:
            yield other_function(i)
```

The idea being that the function can then be used as a generator to build all instances, or it can be used to return a specific instance. Is this a good way to do this in Python? If not, is there a better way.

Comment: I think this works only in Python 3

Comment: ... and even in Python 3 it does not mean what you seem to expect.

Comment: You can make it return either a value or an iterable (e.g. the result of a call to another generator function), but that seems like it would be a terrible idea due to the inconsistency.

Answer (score 20):

Only in Python 3 it is syntactically possible to have `return value` and `yield` in the same function, in Python 2 it will result in:

```
SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator
```

In Python 3 `return value` inside a generator is actually a syntactic sugar for `raise StopIteration(value)`, which is also supported by the `yield from` clause:

```
def f():
    yield from iter('123')
    return 'ok'

def g():
    message = yield from f()
    print('Message:', message)

In [1]: list(g)
Message: ok
Out[1]: ['1', '2', '3']
```

So, this construct does not do what you expect it to. Besides, it does not seem a very good ("pythonic") idea to vary the return type (or, rather, interface) of a function based on the argument value. That may be a matter of taste, though, here is what Guido van Rossum says in his interview in the book [Masterminds of Programming](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596515171.do):

> I have a few personal pet peeves: first of all, and this is specific to dynamic languages, don’t make the return type of a method depend on the value of one of the arguments; otherwise it may be hard to understand what’s returned if you don’t know the relationship—maybe the type-determining argument is passed in from a variable whose content you can’t easily guess while reading the code.

Comment: Could you elucidate your last sentence please? It's a great answer, but why not?

Comment: @DavidBoshton I've updated the answer. Basically, that brings less surprises and makes the code easier to comprehend in the future. There are no rules without exceptions, of course, if you know what you're doing.

Comment: This is also [explictely documented](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions): *Using a yield expression in a function’s body causes that function to be a generator*. It doesn't matter beyond this point. You use `yield`, it is a generator function, end of. Reachability doesn't come into play here.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to return either an instance or a generator, for example if you have a function that may accept a number or an iterable. In the case of the number argument, you may just want the result rather than a generator.

```
def f(n):
    if not hasattr(n, '__iter__'):
        n = (n,)

    for i in n:
        yield(i)

list(f(range(5)))
>>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

list(f(5))
>>> [5]
```

In this case a single number in a list may not be what you want.

As described by other commentators on this post, a function containing `yield` will always return a generator, so adding `return` to the function does not work:

```
def f(n):
    if not hasattr(n, '__iter__'):
        n = (n,)

    if len(n) == 1:
        return n
    else:
        for i in n:
           yield(i)

f(5)
>>> <generator object f at 0x7f939460e3c0>
```

One solution is to wrap the function doing the work in another function:

```
def _f(n):
    for i in n:
        yield(i)

def f(n):
    if not hasattr(n, '__iter__'):
        n = (n,)
    
    # do 'heavy' lifting in private function
    out = _f(n)
    
    # work out whether to return just the value or the generator
    if len(n) == 1:
        return next(out)
    else:
        return out

f(5)
>>> 5

f(range(5))
>>> <generator object _f at 0x7f939460e900>

list(f(range(5))
>>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This way you can get just the result if you only need one iteration, but still return a generator if you need more than one.

Answer (score 0):

A common idiom, to yield multiple items, or return a single item as a special case:

```py
def foo(bar=None):
    if bar:
        yield other_function(other_thing[bar])
    else:
        for i in other_thing:
            yield other_function(i)
```

Or if you like more flattened code:

```py
def foo(bar=None):
    if bar:
        yield other_function(other_thing[bar])
        return

    for i in other_thing:
        yield other_function(i)
```

The function `foo` always returns an iterator:

```py
for item in foo():
    ...
```