# Return with argument inside generator

Tags: python, json, generator, readfile

I know there's a similar question already asked, but doesn't answer what I need, as mine is a little different.

My code:

```
def tFileRead(fileName, JSON=False):
    with open(fileName) as f:
        if JSON:
            return json.load(f)
        for line in f:
            yield line.rstrip('\n')
```

What I want to do:
if `JSON` is true, it means its reading from a json file and I want to return `json.load(f)`, otherwise, I want to yield the lines of the file into a generator.

I've tried the alternative of converting the generator into json, but that got very messy, very fast, and doesn't work very well.

Comment: if not a JSON try returning a closure that is a generator

Comment: a single function has to either return or yield. not both

Comment: You could `yield from json.load`, but this will only yield the keys from the dict. How do you plan to use the function in both cases?

Comment: @Aaron Thanks aaron, is there any good way around this, without coding the same function twice, or going messy and putting a sub-function inside this one.

Comment: @tobias_k Case 1: I want a JSON for loading the options for a CLI. the JSON file is functioning like a config file. fileRead, is for reading line by line from a file.

Comment: @Aaron Not true, a function can both yield and return (in Python 3).

Comment: You're trying to make this function do too much... The caller already knows whether it's JSON or not so it's not unreasonable to make it call a function that either returns json or call a function that yields lines - both are entirely different and the caller's going to have to know how to handle the results of each...

Comment: @JonClements doing it that way, I'm turning something that could be an if/else, into two separate functions. Is it bad to split it? Or does it actually make sense, what are the arguments?

Comment: @Islarf You should have two functions - one for json and one for line reading. The caller has the knowledge of whether it's json or not and so it should be responsible for calling the appropriate function and that way it also knows which kind of output it will get from doing so. Making functions too clever or do too much just causes hassle - both for them and for the caller.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Can you explain? When I mix `return` and `yield`, I don't get a syntax error, but on the path that should return, nothing happens, like with an empty generator.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28806583/1639625 Mixing `return` and `yield` seems to do something entirely different...

Comment: @tobias_k Yeah, I think it just adds the `value` attribute to the `StopIteration` exception. Haven't used it yet, I just know about it.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I didn't actually know that.. I still primarily only use 2.7 for compatibility's sake

Comment: @Islarf you should accept an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

The first solution that came to my mind was to explicitly return a generator object which would provide the exact behavior you tried to achieve.

The problem is: if you explicitly returned a generator object like this `return (line.rstrip('\n') for line in f)` the file would be closed after returning and any further reading from the file would raise an exception.

You should write two functions here: one that reads a json file and one for the normal file. Then you can write a wrapper that desides on an argument which of these two functions to call.

Or just move the iteration part into another function like this:

```
def iterate_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as fin:
        for line in fin:
            yield line.rstrip("\n")


def file_read(file_name, as_json=False):
    if as_json:
        with open(file_name) as fin:
            return json.load(fin)
    else:
        return iterate_file(file_name)
```

Comment: Why are you talking about the problem of something they're not doing?

Comment: @StefanPochmann you are right. I'm missing a step here. I was thinking that you could do it that way ... but wait, no that does not work. That's why i mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

You could `yield from` the dictionary loaded with JSON, thus iterating over the key-value-pairs in the dict, but this would not be your desired behaviour.

```
def tFileRead(fileName, JSON=False):
    with open(fileName) as f:
        if JSON:
            yield from json.load(f).items()  # works, but differently
        for line in f:
            yield line.rstrip('\n')
```

It would be nice if you could just return a generator, but this will not work, since using `with`, the file is closed as soon as the function returns, i.e. before the generator is consumed.

```
def tFileRead(fileName, JSON=False):
    with open(fileName) as f:
        if JSON:
            return json.load(f)
        else:
            return (line.rstrip('\n') for line in f)  # won't work
```

Alternatively, you could define another function just for yielding the lines from the file and use that in the generator:

```
def tFileRead(fileName, JSON=False):
    if JSON:
        with open(fileName) as f:
            return json.load(f)
    else:
        def withopen(fileName):
            with open(fileName) as f:
                yield from f
        return (line.rstrip('\n') for line in withopen(fileName))
```

But once you are there, you can really just use two separate functions for reading the file en-block as JSON or for iterating the lines...

Comment: How do you know the JSON loads to a dict, not a list? Also, I find *"if you could just return a generator"* misleading, as you **are** returning a generator (in your first version).

Comment: @StefanPochmann About the dict: You are right, did not think about JSON returning e.g. a list. About returning a generator: I meant returning with `return`, as in the second approach.