# Why is yield "blocking" all other functionality?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yield

I decided to finally learn `yield` to make generators and came across this weird thing:

If I run this code, it prints out `<generator ...>`. It doesn't print `num` or stop execution at `3.1`...

If I remove the for-yield lines, then it works correctly.

```py
def gen(num = 1):
    print(num)
    if num == 1:
        return 3
    if num == 2:
        return 3.1
    
    for i in range(num):
        yield i

print(gen(2))
```

Why does this happen?

I'm using Python 3.8.12

Comment: The presence of `yield` makes it generator, thus you need to "consume" it one way or another. It's another question if it is fine to mix `return` and `yield`

Comment: Mixing return and yield will lead to getting StopIteration exception, which may be acceptable for your usecase. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28806909/6212530

Comment: To get value from generator use `print(next(gen(2)))`.

Comment: @MatijaSirk @buran But why didn't the `print` run then? It ran before either the yield or return correct?

Comment: No, the presence of `yield` makes the whole `gen` a generator

Comment: `print(list(gen(2)))` will consume your generator

Comment: If you do e.g. `print(list(gen(2)))`  it will print `2` and then `[]`. The `2` is from the return and then the generator is empty, so it prints empty list. If you iterate over `for i in gen(2): print(i)` it will print just 2. @MatijaSirk